# How to count posts in loop with infinite scroll?

Tags: wp-query, infinite-scroll

on my `index.php` I display all my posts with infinite scroll. Before the WP loop I added a $counter, which counts up with every post. But if the infinite scroll loads new posts, the counter will be reset.

Example for counter:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
(load new posts)
0
1
2
3
4
.
.
.

What can I do that the counter counts up after loading new post (...,6,7,8,9,10,...)?

Thanks for help!

```
<div class="grid" id="container">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
        <?php $counter = 0;
            if ( have_posts() ) {
                while ( have_posts() ) {
                    the_post();?>
                    <div class="grid-item post-item<?php if($counter % 4 == 0) : ?> opening-box<?php endif; ?>">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
               <?php $counter++; 
               } // end while
            } ?>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you using for infinite scroll?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding this before the loop:

```
$count = $wp_query->post_count;
```

But that may only return the number of posts you have set for posts_per_page, in that case you might be able to use:

```
$count = $wp_query->found_posts;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set your own counter. `WP_Query` offers a method that holds the current post's number, just like the key for an array in a foreach loop.

To access the current post, use `$wp_query->current_post` and as mentioned by the other answer, you can use `$count = $wp_query->found_posts` to count the total of found posts.

Comment: hmm no, he needs the counter to be implemented in JS most likely or returned as part of the response